# Update WPF Application Programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I'm trying to update my WPF application manually, I found the following procedures:

```
    private void InstallUpdateSyncWithInfo()
    {
        UpdateCheckInfo info = null;

        if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
        {
            ApplicationDeployment ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;

            try
            {
                info = ad.CheckForDetailedUpdate();

            }
            catch (DeploymentDownloadException dde)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The new version of the application cannot be downloaded at this time. \n\nPlease check your network connection, or try again later. Error: " + dde.Message);
                return;
            }
            catch (InvalidDeploymentException ide)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot check for a new version of the application. The ClickOnce deployment is corrupt. Please redeploy the application and try again. Error: " + ide.Message);
                return;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ioe)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This application cannot be updated. It is likely not a ClickOnce application. Error: " + ioe.Message);
                return;
            }

            if (info.UpdateAvailable)
            {
                Boolean doUpdate = true;

                if (!info.IsUpdateRequired)
                {
                    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("An update is available. Would you like to update the application now?", "Update Available", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
                    if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                    {
                        doUpdate = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Display a message that the app MUST reboot. Display the minimum required version.
                    MessageBox.Show("This application has detected a mandatory update from your current " +
                        "version to version " + info.MinimumRequiredVersion.ToString() +
                        ". The application will now install the update and restart.",
                        "Update Available", MessageBoxButton.OK,
                        MessageBoxImage.Information);
                }

                if (doUpdate)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ad.Update();
                        MessageBox.Show("The application has been upgraded, and will now restart.");
                        Application.Current.Shutdown();
                    }
                    catch (DeploymentDownloadException dde)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Cannot install the latest version of the application. \n\nPlease check your network connection, or try again later. Error: " + dde);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Calls the procedure from button event:

```
        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            InstallUpdateSyncWithInfo();
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(er.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
```

I can't debug the application because it required to be in Network Deployed mode.

I uploaded the newest version of my application on my server online, and specify a location for updates in application properties.

After run the application and hit the update button I get the following error :

[image]

Please, Can you help me to solve this issue.

[SOURSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx)

Thanks in advance

Abdulsalam.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial on CodeProject:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/731954/Simple-Auto-Update-Let-your-application-update-i

I find it is the best solution out there (especially if your looking to avoid ClickOnce) and gives about every possible feature you'd need and is insanely easy to customize.

These are the basic and amazing features:

- Check a remote site via HTTP for a newer version.
- If a newer version is available, download it as a ZIP.
- Ensure successful download before overwriting anything.
- Make it easy to add to any application as a component.
- Allow updating of the application itself.
- Do not require a bootstrapper, or multi-step process.
- Resist tampering.
- Accommodate some simple logging.
- Single XML file configuration.

I also managed to go as far as coding my own update dialog that shows progress as files download. This, unfortunately, is not included in the article.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the new version of your application requires higher trust than your old one, and you're running with Trusted Application Deployment? In that case, no prompting for trust levels will occur. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01daf08f.aspx for more insights.

The latter page notes under Trusted Application Deployment and Permission Elevation: "If the current publisher is not a trusted publisher, trust manager will use Permission Elevation to query the user about whether he or she wants to grant your application elevated permissions. If permission elevation is disabled by the administrator, however, the application cannot obtain permission to run. The application will not run and no notification will be displayed to the user."